# Moving calculations using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, calculated-columns, calculation

I need to calculate a new column using moving calculations.

For example, I have a table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 |
| 11 | 14 |
| 12 | 13 |

I need to calculate new column where the **1st value** is calculated like `5000/10*15`, the **2nd value** is `(5000 / 10 * 15) / 11 * 14`, the **3rd one** is `((5000 / 10 * 15) / 11 * 14) / 12 * 13` and **so on**. Where 5000 is a random value and in the future I will use it like a parameter in a stored procedure.

I know, that in Excel for example we can reffer to the previous calculated cell. How can it be calculated using SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: Please have a go and show us what you tried and where you got stuck!

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi-)sets.  Your table has no apparent ordering.  If the first column is used for this purpose, you should be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table #test (A int,B int)

insert into #test values(10,15),(11,14),(12,13)

declare @seed int=5000;

;with temp as (
 select A,B,row_number() over(order by a) rn from #test
),
cte as
(
 select @seed/A*B  calculated,rn from temp where rn=1
 union all
 select c. calculated/t.A*t.B,t.rn from temp t
 join cte c on t.rn=c.rn+1
)
select * from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning in the docs that reads:

> If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement,
> SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the
> expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are
> references among the assignments.
> It means there is no guarantee that it will evaluate the expression left-to-right. For this code:

```
declare @a int, @b int;
select @a = 2, @b = @a * 3;
select @a, @b;
```

The result could be 2, 6 (@a = ... evaluated first) or 2, NULL (@b = ... evaluated first).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. But I'm not sure that it is what I really need.